# Firefox can't open tradingview chart, but Chrome can. on the same network environment

Tags: firefox

[image]

[image]

From the console it keeps loading some resources:

```
2022-01-23T15:53:26.686Z:Alerts.Screener.Dispatcher:Error: Receive screener alerts snapshot timeout: 4 main_chart.3a34030d94c5f1691fc6.js:792:2438
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://prodata.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart%2FbRlnkhT8%2F&date=2022_01_21-11_27. bRlnkhT8:18:1051
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://prodata.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart%2FbRlnkhT8%2F&date=2022_01_21-11_27. bRlnkhT8:18:1051
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://pushstream.tradingview.com/message-pipe-ws/private_fzrUpGntAl3EC9SLyKFu9IgriCd-LHOlDBDcaLQrEaM. main_chart.3a34030d94c5f1691fc6.js:795:237
The connection to https://charts-storage-notifications.tradingview.com/charts-storage/layout/bRlnkhT8/subscribe?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IkFod2IiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJ0dl9jaGFydCIsImlhdCI6MTY0Mjk1MDAwMCwiZXhwIjoxNjQzODE3NjAwLCJ0eXBlIjoib3duZXIiLCJsYXlvdXRJZCI6ImJSbG5raFQ4Iiwib3duZXJJZCI6OTkyNTg3Niwic2hhcmVkIjpmYWxzZX0.f0rT-t4YKZqSRJ0TY3_kjz0dkmO-hQyvg97MqrgnyOHiRezyM32-ESOmtsX8XsjmUF53bFcZKGW6NAgBWCoueMi8dN3_N4eohGLxfUIJxv_nIMkDWPbVXYNHJgNEVq8H8GmaAzSQVhjNurVbo-NB1ObVhMw8BmOSk_PrIk4yA8Dqf3Icr5f-Yas0btyBmu6M8g1pwAK_tChr6SUb6kZV0WyUivEgxulM5TuYQTK4Pwp9TyQPuVFQh1P0Uv1_aq0oWC_Iwf9PyPn4vKZdvNsFuWWknp1xxAHk69P0ck-feLO4Giay5TR1q5xvYLYXx9dTRsmy1nj_3DXKF6EaJpRPIw was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

The version is : `96.0.2`

Chrome is working well on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "NSURLSession WebSocket" resolves the issue for me. Had a similar issue but on safari